# Embedding resources after build?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I currently have a build setup as follows, allowing me to embed all references DLLs as embedded resources in my assembly. This operates at the `AfterResolveReferences` target and works flawlessly. It also allows me to produce a single executable which doesn't need any additional DLLs to launch (since it loads these at runtime).

Now, I would like to include the PDB information as well. I already do this with all referenced assemblies, but not the assembly I am building, since that is (for obvious reasons) produced *after* that target.

To recap:

1. I am building AssemblyA.exe.
2. It has AssemblyB.dll and AssemblyC.dll as references, so these are included in AssemblyA.exe as embedded resources during build.
3. After building AssemblyA.exe, MSBuild also produces a AssemblyA.pdb file.
4. This is where I want to then also embed AssemblyA.pdb into AssemblyA.exe as embedded resource.

Is that possible somehow? I am aware that this may trigger a double-build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up writing the following to my project file - works flawlessly. It does a double-build, but it works.

```
  <Target Name="Prebuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="Clean" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionPath)" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=Debug;IgnoreRecursion=true" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_IgnoreRecursion Include="$(IgnoreRecursion)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <CallTarget Targets="Prebuild" Condition="'%(_IgnoreRecursion.Identity)' != 'true'" />
    <CreateItem Include="$(TargetDir)\**\*.*">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="OutputFiles" />
    </CreateItem>
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@(OutputFiles)" Condition="('%(OutputFiles.Extension)' == '.dll' Or '%(OutputFiles.Extension)' == '.pdb')">
        <LogicalName>%(OutputFiles.DestinationSubDirectory)%(OutputFiles.Filename)%(OutputFiles.Extension)</LogicalName>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Embedding: @(OutputFiles->'%(Filename)%(Extension)', ', ')" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

If a double compile is not a problem you can create your own target, compile to a temporay folder via msbuild task and then embed the files you need from this temporary folder.

You have to do a rebuild because otherwise it will cache the assemblies.

Your target to compile in the .proj file would look like this:

```
 <Target Name="YourBuild">
     <MSBuild Projects="YourProject.csproj" Targets="Build"
          Properties="Configuration=Debug;OutputPath=tmp"/>
     <MSBuild Projects="YourProject.csproj" Targets="Rebuild"
          Properties="Configuration=Debug"/>
 </Target>
```

Files that are included as EmbeddedResoucre in BeforeBuild target in the project:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <YourFiles Include="tmp\*.pdb" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource  Include="@(YourFiles ->'%(Relativedir)%(filename)%(extension)')"/>
    </ItemGroup> 
  </Target>
```

Comment: Very interesting! Is it possible to somehow not have it be part of a target?

Comment: I was thinking about that. The problem is that you somehow need to rebuild the project inside the same project. Not sur this is possible, I doubt it.  Also doing it in a separate build file for publishing seems cleaner to me.

Comment: MSBuild does perform a new build (without skipping over it) if at least one build property changed, compared to the last build within the same process.